# RequiredFieldValidator on individual Field

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a repeater that requires a validator on only some of the fields. So for instance, I have a set of TextBoxes for each field, but I would only want fields like First/Last Name as required, while Date of Birth would not be necessary. I have tried something along the lines of:

```
protected void repCustomerDetails_DataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        TextBox tct = e.Item.FindControl("tbColumns") as TextBox;
        Label lbl = e.Item.FindControl("Label1") as Label;

        RequiredFieldValidator rfv = (RequiredFieldValidator)e.Item.FindControl("rfvColumns");

        if (lbl.Text != "DOB")
        {
            rfv.ControlToValidate = tct.ID;
        }

    }
}
```

but it's not quite working, as this validates every textbox due to the shared ID tag.

```
        <asp:Repeater ID="repCustomerDetail" runat="server" onitemdatabound="repCustomerDetails_DataBound">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(((RepeaterItem)Container).DataItem, "FieldName")%>' Width="140px"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="tbColumns" runat="server" Width="160px" Visible='<%# (((bool)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IsDropDown") == false &&  (string)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Type") != "Boolean") ? true : false )%> '></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlField" runat="server" Width="165px" Visible='<%# ((bool)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IsDropDown") == true ? true : false )%> '></asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbField" runat="server" Visible='<%# (((bool)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IsDropDown") == false &&  (string)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Type") == "Boolean")? true : false )%> ' />
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnCalendar" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/WebResources/Images/calendar.gif" Visible='<%# ((string)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Type") == "DateTime" ? true : false )%> ' />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvColumns" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbColumns" ErrorMessage="* Required" ValidationGroup="Save">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtendeeer" runat="server" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" PopupButtonID="imgbtnCalendar" TargetControlID="tbColumns" Enabled='<%# ((string)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Type") == "DateTime" ? true : false )%> '></ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
                        <br id="Br1" runat="server" visible="<%# Container.ItemIndex == 3 %>" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Can you show us your frontend code in the .ascx/.aspx file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling the `RequiredFieldValidator` for the Date of Birth field:

```
RequiredFieldValidator rfv = (RequiredFieldValidator)e.Item.FindControl("rfvColumns");

rfv.Enabled = lbl.Text != "DOB";
```

If you need to make it dynamic, you could have a "Required" property on you DataSource, then you could use it to handle the `RequiredFieldValidator` enabling.

Example:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvColumns" Enabled='<%# Eval("Required") %>' runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbColumns" ErrorMessage="* Required" ValidationGroup="Save" >*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: Thanks Man, that's really cool.  I've used rfv.Enabled = lbl.Text != "DOB" && lbl.Text != "Phone";

Comment: You mentioned dynamic validation enabling, if I gave my DataSource a Required column, how exactly would I check that against the required field validator?

Comment: Updated the answer with an example. It would basically use the `Required` property to set the `RequiredFieldValidator`'s Enabled property.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much, I'd vote your answer up twice if I could haha